# What's it called when a compound word can be split up in diff ways to present alt meanings?

Tags: puns

For instance, is the pet store PETSMART meant to be Pets Mart, or Pet Smart? That's not actually my question, as I'm pretty sure it's Pet Smart. I'm just asking what it's called when a word either CAN be split into multiple ways to present alternative meanings, or WAS MEANT TO be able to be interpreted two or more different ways through this method.

If you're wondering the source of the question, there is a game on Kickstarter right now called PooPride featuring human waste as protagonists. And given that it's a racing game, I imagine the name is meant to have a second meaning as Poop Ride.

Comment: What don't you like about "pun"?

Comment: Seemed to me to have enough room within pun to be a specialized category of pun, perhaps.

Comment: But yeah it looks like that other question covered the topic well enough.

Comment: I've never heard a specific word for this. It's just another kind of play on words.

Comment: I'll bet the people behind PetSmart did that deliberately, too. The coloring of the logo and capitalization in text make Pet Smart the primary meaning, but they're a store and _mart_ means store, so you do the math (or English, in this case).

Comment: @ermanen I'm not sure this is quite the same as that question, which seems to be about words that are hard to parse because they can be split up differently. This question is more about words that are deliberately punned.